# AutoLayout animation causes subview layout issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a vertical navigation bar that lays out the items within it using `AutoLayout`. When I animate the navigation bar's position on and off screen, the layout of the items within the navigation bar is incorrect. Items are resized as if the bar is shrinking in width, when that is, in fact, not occurring. What am I doing wrong?

Video of issue (note that I colored the background of each button red so you can see it more easily):
"[Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4825154/Autolayout%20bug%202.mov)".

Code animating the navigation bar (in the view controller):

```
self.verticalNavBarLeadingSpace.constant = hidden ? -self.verticalNavBarWidth.constant : 0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut  
             animations:^{
                 [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
             }
             completion:nil];
```

The `-updateConstraints` method in my view (using [FLK+AutoLayout](https://github.com/floriankugler/FLKAutoLayout) to create constraints):

```
- (void) updateConstraints
{
// Wipe out existing constraints
[self removeConstraints:self.addedConstraints];
[self.addedConstraints removeAllObjects];

UIButton *lastItem;
NSString *height = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", self.itemHeight];
for (UIButton *btn in _items) {
    [self.addedConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[btn constrainHeight:height]];
    [self.addedConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[btn alignLeading:@"0" trailing:@"0" toView:self]];

    if (!lastItem) {
        [self.addedConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[btn alignTopEdgeWithView:self predicate:@"0"]];
    } else {
        [self.addedConstraints addObjectsFromArray:[btn constrainTopSpaceToView:lastItem predicate:@"0"]];
    }

    lastItem = btn;
}

[super updateConstraints];
}
```

Comment: Inside UIView animation you should be modifying the constraint to achieve the animation if I am not mistaken. You could change the constraint for the animation for example to achieve some animation, you want.

Comment: The animation of the sidebar positioning constraint is not the issue. As shown in the video, this works fine. The problem I'm trying to solve is that the buttons within the sidebar are resizing during the animation when they shouldn't be.